# Ubuntu 12.10 won't use dhcp static lease from my router

Tags: dhcp, router

I have a Buffalo router running dd-wrt (came stock from the factory with it). I have a DHCP static lease setup for my computer which dual boots Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10.  When running Windows, there is no problem getting the IP address I assigned in the static lease.  However, when booting Ubuntu, it refuses to get the IP address I assigned and just gets the first available dhcp address.  Obviously the mac address is the same and the hostname is also set the same though I don't think hostname is used by the router.  This is not just isolated to one Ubuntu machine on my network.  My usual fix it to just configure the Ubuntu machine with a fixed ip address that matches the static lease address, but I found on this machine that is causing a problem with ssh connections dropping every few minutes (different issue, different question to come).

So, why does it seem every Ubuntu machine I have won't get the static lease address automatically and is there something I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a NAS box on my network that had it's dhcp server turned on.  My Ubuntu machines were getting their dhcp addresses from the NAS instaed of the router.